# Count values matching row and column variable

Tags: excel

I need to count how many "1" that match a row and column condition.

Here's an example:

[image]

As I said, I want to count all "1" that cond1 matches "1" and cond2 matches "1". The result should be 2.

I've started with this function, without success:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(B4:C10,MATCH(1,A4:A10,0),MATCH(1,B3:C3,0)),1)
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: MATCH only returns the first match.  Are the column headers unique?

Comment: Yes, the column headers are unique. the row headers don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS and remove the match on column A into its own range and criteria:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$4:$A$10,1,INDEX($B$4:$C$10,0,MATCH(1,$B$3:$C$3,0)),1)
```

[image]

---

Another option using SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A4:A10=1)*(B3:C3=1)*(B4:C10=1))
```

[image]